# Lightbox image is bigger than lightbox itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have the following problem: My LightBox (latest version from git behaves as latest stable) is shown correctly in Firefox and Midori, but in Chromium (V32, Debian testing) the picture is a little bit bigger than lightbox:

http://picload.org/image/laciaad/bildschirmfoto1.png

I have the following code:

```
<script src="modernizr.custom.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script src="lightbox-2.6.min.js">
</script>
<link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="index.html">
  Back to index
</a>
<h1>
  My pictures
</h1>
<br />
<i>
  Some pictures from me.
</i>
<br />
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5719.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="Let's have a meal">
  <img src="thumbs/mypics/IMG_5719.JPG" alt="Let's have a meal" />
</a>
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5719.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="Let's have a meal">
  Test
</a>
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5721.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="A piece to eat">
  <img src="thumbs/mypics/IMG_5721.JPG" alt="A piece to eat" />
</a>
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5721.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="A piece to eat">
  Test
</a>
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5724.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="Window">
  <img src="thumbs/mypics/IMG_5724.JPG" alt="Window" />
</a>
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5724.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="Window">
  Test
</a>
```

All files are existing, no 404s.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just edit the width and height of the image inline to get the image the size you need it?

ex:

```
<a href="images/mypics/IMG_5724.JPG" data-lightbox="mypics" title="Window">
    <img src="thumbs/mypics/IMG_5724.JPG" width="XXX" height="XXX" alt="Window" />
</a>
```

Comment: This is crazy in firefox...only chromium makes problems. Is there a known bug? I can't find anything :(